# Stack - Linkedlist implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

```
bool LinkedStack<ItemType>::push(const ItemType& newItem)
{
    Node<ItemType>* newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(newItem, topPtr);               
    topPtr = newNodePtr;
   newNodePtr = nullptr;

    return true;
}
```

I am a bit confused on why we have to do newNodePtr = nullptr in this push function.
To my understanding, we create the node, set its data with netItem, and set its next to topPtr which would the first item in the stack. We then set topPtr to point to the newNodePtr that we just created.. After that line I am not sure on why we set the newNodePtr to nullPtr.. wouldnt that cause us to lose the rest of the chain.. Can someone please explain this one line and why its used here for the stack..

Comment: Is it C++? Add the language tag.

Comment: "...why we have to do.." - you don't. You don't even need that variable: `topPtr = new Node<ItemType>(newItem, topPtr);` is sufficient.

Comment: what would be the reason of setting newNodePtr to nullPtr in this case?

Comment: I can't think of any reason. newNodePtr falls out of scope after the following line.

Comment: Ask the author. I see no need for the var (or the return value for that matter), much less a reason to null it.

Comment: @georgiyd91 Yes, that's correct. it simply holds an address, one which you save to `topPtr` regardless, so it is pretty-much uselessIf you're debugging and want to see both the new node *and* the old top the new node's `next` pointer already holds the old top. So yeah, its worthless.

Comment: Okay that makes it clear for me. My understanding was flawed. Thanks for the help gentlemen.